# Setonitemclicklistener not working in run()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In the following code the setonitemclicklistener of listView not working. I don't know what is missing.

```
public class OffersActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> offersList;
OfferAdapter offerAdapter;  
JSONArray offers = null;
private static final String OFFER_URL = "My URL of PHP file";

 static final String OFFER_ID = "offer_id";
 static final String OFFER_CONTENT = "offer_content";
 static final String OFFER_PHOTO = "offer_photo";
 static final String OFFER_PHOTO_THUMB = "offer_photo_thumb";
 static final String OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO = "offer_internal_photo";
 static final String OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO_THUMB = "offer_internal_photo_thumb";
 static final String OFFER_CREATED_DATE = "offer_created_date";
 static final String OFFER_ORD = "offer_ord";
 static final String OFFER_STATE = "offer_state";
 static final String OFFER_LAST_UPDATE = "offer_last-update";
 static final String OFFER_TITLE = "offer_title";
 static final String OFFER_OLD_PRICE = "offer_old_price";
 static final String OFFER_CURRENT_PRICE = "offer_current_price";
 static final String OFFER_OCAZION = "offer_ocazion";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.offers_list);
    offersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     new LoadOffer().execute();
}
class LoadOffer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(OffersActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loadOffers));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(OFFER_URL, "GET",params);
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        Log.d("Offer JSON: ", jsonArray.toString());

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String offer_id = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_ID);
                String offer_content = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_CONTENT);
                String offer_photo = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_PHOTO);
                String offer_photo_thumb = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_PHOTO_THUMB);
                String offer_internal_photo = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO);
                String offer_internal_photo_thumb = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO_THUMB);
                String offer_created_date = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_CREATED_DATE);
                String offer_ord = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_ORD);
                String offer_state = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_STATE);
                String offer_last_update = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_LAST_UPDATE);
                String offer_title = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_TITLE);
                String offer_old_price = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_OLD_PRICE);
                String offer_current_price = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_CURRENT_PRICE);
                String offer_ocazion = jsonObject.getString(OFFER_OCAZION);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(OFFER_ID, offer_id);
                map.put(OFFER_CONTENT, offer_content);
                map.put(OFFER_PHOTO, offer_photo);
                map.put(OFFER_PHOTO_THUMB, offer_photo_thumb);
                map.put(OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO, offer_internal_photo);
                map.put(OFFER_INTERNAL_PHOTO_THUMB, offer_internal_photo_thumb);
                map.put(OFFER_CREATED_DATE, offer_created_date);
                map.put(OFFER_ORD, offer_ord);
                map.put(OFFER_STATE, offer_state);
                map.put(OFFER_LAST_UPDATE, offer_last_update);
                map.put(OFFER_TITLE, offer_title);
                map.put(OFFER_OLD_PRICE, offer_old_price);
                map.put(OFFER_CURRENT_PRICE, offer_current_price);
                map.put(OFFER_OCAZION, offer_ocazion);

                offersList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                offerAdapter = new OfferAdapter(OffersActivity.this, offersList);
                setListAdapter(offerAdapter);

                getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
                            // not work..
                        Toast.makeText(OffersActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // not work too..
                        System.out.println("Hello");
                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

Comment: you no need to use runOnUiThread(new Runnable() in onPostExecute() method..onPostExecute always executes in UI thread.the problem is not this post your layout files also..

Comment: is it throwing any exception?

Comment: this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589416/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-executing

Answer (score 0):

remove run thread  .. crate one listview in xml 
write below code

```
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
          @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question